# How do I change my Google account login email?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a Google account where I have to login using a Gmail address which is not my primary contact email. This is problematic because every time someone wants to share a Google doc with me, naturally they will send it to my primary email which I cannot access with my Gmail account.

I want to change my Google account to a non Gmail account email address. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en).

**Change your username**

**If you use Gmail with your Google Account**, *it's not currently possible to change your Gmail username after you've registered unless you want to delete Gmail from your account* and use a different, non-Gmail address for your Google Account. You can also [create another Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https://accounts.google.com/ManageAccount) with a different Gmail username.

**If you *don't* use Gmail with your Google Account**, you can change your account username to another email address at any time. Your username is the full email address you used to create your account.

To change the email address on your account, just follow these steps:

1. Visit the [Google Accounts homepage](https://accounts.google.com/Login).
2. Sign in to your account.
3. Click **Change** in the **Email addresses** section.
4. Enter your new email address and your current password.
5. Click **Save email address**.

Once you've saved the change, you should receive a verification message at the email address you just entered. To complete the change, you'll need to click the verification link in this message. You should also receive a message at your old email address confirming that we've registered the change to your account. If you don't receive the verification email, [check your spam folders or request a new email](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27447).

**Note:**

- You can't change the email address on your account to an existing
  Gmail address, but we invite you to [add a new Gmail address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/72198) to your
  Google Account.
- You can't change the email address on your account to an email
  address that's already associated with a Google Account.
- If you want to make your alternate email address the new primary
  address, you'll first need to [delete your alternate email address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/76143)
  from the account.
- The account username that you choose needs to be an active, valid
  email address that you can access.

**Delete Gmail from your Google Account**

Please note that by doing so, you'll lose access to your inbox, and you won't be able to sign in with your Gmail username any longer. If you want to re-add Gmail to this Google Account in the future, you'll have to re-use your old Gmail username. Learn how to [delete Gmail from your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177).

Comment: How do I go about deleting the gmail from my account? And what does delete gmail from your account exactly mean? The entire account is gone with all the emails? Can I assign the gmail account a different login name?

Comment: @erotsppa, I'd recommend just creating another Google Account with the Gmail username you'd prefer.

Comment: That`s idea really more helpful for me.

Comment: So in good ol' 2021 (8 years after this question has been asked), I tried deleting Gmail from my Google Account with the intention of "changing my Gmail address" via deleting Gmail and re-creating it under a different name, but that does not work. After you delete Gmail from your Google Account, you can't re-create your Gmail with a different username. If you go back to Gmail after you've deleted it, it'll force you to use the same username.

Yes, I know the answer says all these things but sometimes you don't read and think you can outsmart the system.